# PDFBOX Generar PDF- Cómo colocar un Párrafo con algunas palabras en negrita, colocar el párrafo en varias líneas y justificado

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox2.0

Estoy utilizando PDFBOX para generar un certificado. El cuerpo tiene un párrafo con algunas palabras que deben ir en negrita, el texto del párrafo debe dejarse en varias líneas y justificado. Logré colocar el texto del párrafo en varias líneas y justificado colocando todo el párrafo en un sola variable tipo String, pero no se como hacer para colocar solo algunas palabras en negrita, y lograr organizar todo el texto en varias líneas y justificado. Adjunto el extracto de código. Gracias por sus sugerencias

```
DFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
PDRectangle mediabox = page.getMediaBox();
float margin = 72;
float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2*margin;
float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin -250;
String textFirst = "Que el señor (a) " + s +" "+ empleado.getApellidos() + ",  identificado (a) con " + listTipo.get(0).getTIP_CVALOR() +
                       " No. " + empleado.getCedula() + ",  se encuentra vinculado (a) a esta compañía con un contrato " + listContrato.get(0).getTIP_CVALOR() +
                       ", desde el día "+ diaString + "("+ diaIngreso +")" +" del mes de " + mesString + " de "+ anioString + "("+ anioIngreso + ")" + 
                       ", a la fecha, desempeñándose como " + cargo.getNombre() + "."; 
String textSecond = "Se expide la presente certificación a solicitud del interesado (a), a los " + diaActualString + "(" + diaActual+ ")"+ 
                       " días del mes de " + mesActualString + " de " + anioActualString + "(" + anioActual + ")" + ".";
    List<String> listText = new ArrayList<String>();
    listText.add(textFirst);
    listText.add(textSecond);
for (String text : listText) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        int lastSpace = -1;
        while (text.length() > 0)
        {
            int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
            if (spaceIndex < 0)
                spaceIndex = text.length();
            String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
            float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
            if (size > width)
            {
                if (lastSpace < 0)
                    lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
                lines.add(subString);
                text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
                lastSpace = -1;
            }
            else if (spaceIndex == text.length())
            {
                lines.add(text);
                text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                lastSpace = spaceIndex;
            }
        }
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, startY);
        startY = startY - 90;

        //Justificar texto
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) 
        {
            float charSpacing = 0;
            if (lines.get(i).length() > 1)
            {
                float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(lines.get(i)) / 1000;
                float free = width - size;
                if (free > 0)
                {
                    charSpacing = free / (lines.get(i).length() - 1);
                }
            }
            int sizeLines = lines.size()-1;
            if(sizeLines == i) {
                contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(0);
            } else {
                contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(charSpacing);
            }
            contentStream.showText(lines.get(i));
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
        }
        contentStream.endText();
```

Comment: Que tal Yeimy, creo que esto puede ayudarte: [PDFBOX Same Stream with bold and normal text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21573253/11495390)

Comment: Gracias @YemisiSCG por responder. Ya lo intenté, separando el texto del párrafo y colocando a cada uno la fuente respectiva, el problema es que después de hacer esto ya no se puede colocar en varias líneas, ni justificar, o por lo menos no he logrado hacerlo.